# Can anyone tell me why the value of the variable "item" is UNDEFINED?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

*So I'm trying to manipulate the string at a specific index. I have to store the element at a specific index to the "item" variable. But it somehow has the value "undefined". Can anyone tell me what's happening ? Thanks !! *

```js
"use strict";

const shinigami = function (string) {
  //   console.log(string);
  const array = string.split("");
  //   console.log(array);
  for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i] === "M") {
      console.log(array.indexOf("M"));
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
    } else if (array[i] === "N") {
      const item = array[i + 1];
      console.log(item); // Console:  Value of item is UNDEFINED !!
    }
  }
  console.log(array);
};

const string = "abcdNefgh";
shinigami(string);
```

Comment: When using `for(let i in array)` you don't need to use `array[i]`, just use `i` immediately instead.

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji No, that's not true. `i` will be the key of the enumerable property.

Comment: A guess, but `i + 1`, where i = 4 results in 41, and not (4+1=) 5. You could see this simply by debugging the code.

Comment: @Ivar Yes, I'm sorry, I meant `for(let i of array)` not in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some issues with the `const item = array[i + 1]` line. If you do a `console.log` on something like `i + 5` it will become a string value.

This code seems to work when replacing the loop with a for loop with a defined number index:

```
"use strict";

const shinigami = function (string) {
  //   console.log(string);
  const array = string.split("");
  //   console.log(array);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === "M") {
      console.log(array.indexOf("M"));
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
    } else if (array[i] === "N") {
      const item = array[i + 1];
      console.log(item); // Console:  Value of item is not UNDEFINED !!
    }
  }
  console.log(array);
};

const string = "abcdNefgh";
shinigami(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your value of `i` is a string. And if you add number into string like this: `"abc" + 1` is `"abc1"` also if you add `"1"+2` is `"12"` not `3`.

```js
"use strict";

const shinigami = function (string) {
  //   console.log(string);
  const array = string.split("");
  //   console.log(array);
  for (var i in array) {
    if (array[i] === "M") {
      //console.log(array.indexOf("M"));
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
    } else if (array[i] === "N") {
      const item = array[i + 1];
      console.log(array, array[i], array[i + 1], i, i+1);
    }
  }
  //console.log(array);
};

const string = "abcdNefgh";
shinigami(string);
```

If you want to fix it you can convert `i` into a number. Like this:

```js
"use strict";

const shinigami = function (string) {
  const array = string.split("");

  for (const i in array) {

    if (array[i] === "M") {

      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
      array.splice(array.indexOf("M") - 1, 1);
    } else if (array[i] === "N") {
      const item = array[~~i + 1];
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
};

const string = "abcdNefgh";
shinigami(string);
```

Comment: Why do you create unnecessary 2 variables? `i = Number(i);` or even `i = ~~i;` would do just fine.

Comment: yeah, it's true. So I will edit my code :) thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

It's because `i` contains a string, not a number, so by adding 1 to it you create `41` not `5`

Convert it to number with `array[~~i + 1]`

Answer (score -1):

because its doing concatenation instead of add

you can do this way, there are more ways

```
const item = array[eval(i) + eval(1)];
```

or use ++i

Comment: `eval ()` is extreme here...`eval(1)` makes no sense..

Comment: :D yes.   ++i is the simple solution in this case or just redefine the for loop with i